# How to play videos with audio in J2ME

Tags: video, java-me, mmapi

I am trying to play a video (in simulator) by writing an application in J2ME. I am able to play the audio associated with it, but cannot play the video.

Can someone tell me the relative settings (file location, type of simulator,sdk etc..,) to be made in order to play it?

Comment: You need to read about [JSR 135](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Video Type and Simulator 
e.g. WTK 2.2 or WTK 2.5 Emulator does not support 3gp video. But you can play mpg video on these emulator.